# Regex for validating decimal number with fixed range

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I require a regex to validate fixed range decimal numbers e.g. 1234.1234 - valid, 4444.1234 - valid 123.123 - invalid, 1234.123 - invalid

The number 4 digit before decimal and 4 digit after decimal only valid.
I'm currently uses this regex -  `/^\S((\d{4})((\.\d{4})?))$/`  but this not satisfies me.

Comment: did you want to match whole numbers?

Comment: why regex? it might be both faster and safer to just parse the number and check the range using numerical comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\d{4}(\.\d{4})?$
```

This should do it for you.Use

```
^[1-9]\d{3}(\.\d{4})?$
```

If you dont want to match `0234.1234`

Comment: I modified your regex - ^\d{4}(\.\d{4})?$  to new - ^\d{4}\.\d{4}$ for matching only the number 4 digit before decimal and 4 digit after decimal. I think this is correct one. what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\d{4}(?:\.\d{4})?$/
```

This will match `1234` or `1234.5678` as valid matched.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/2)